# Mac Mini TAOP--124 Hardware Test

Tags: mac, hard-drive, hardware, mac-mini, sata

I recently bought a Mac Mini which I knew was missing the hard drive, so easy fix right? Whenever I start the Mac the fans are running really high and the odd thing is I can only start the Mac in safe mode otherwise it will go into a boot loop.

I did a PRAM/SMC reset, but no result. I performed an Apple Hardware Test and I got an error:
4SNS/1/C0000008 TAOP-- 124: Ambient Temperature Sensor

I tried to connect an other Mac Mini's sensor but that didn't work either. The thing is, the Mac runs from an external harddrive connected to the Mac through SATA to USB. It is missing the internal SATA. Can it have something to do with the missing SATA? Or has anyone else fixed this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not likely related your SATA drive because (besides it being specifically referenced to unencoded) [decoding that error code](https://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-invoke-and-interpret-the-apple-hardware-tests/) tells us that it's the Ambient Temp Sensor.

- 4SNES = System Error
- T = Temperature
- A = Ambient

If it had anything to do with the drive, you would see an "H" in the code - like THxx)

This is something that you will need to replace.

[image]

Comment: Than it should be fixed? Great thank you very much!

Comment: Can it also be the socket, or is this for sure the cable itself? Is there a way to know before I order one?

Comment: Socket?  Not likely.  It is possible, however, that the circuitry that connects the sensor to the SMC is faulty (bad resistor, capacitor, etc.) But short of removing the logic board, getting the schematics, diagnostic equipment, and having the skills to do such a test, this is a much easier and cost effective solution.  If it fails with a known good component, it's you logic board.

Comment: Thank you very much Allan! Will order a cable and check it out

Comment: Hi Alan, I ordered the sensor and got it in the mail today. But I can't find the sensor socket from the Mac Mini (2011). Is this cable also usable for the Mac Mini 2011? And is there a way to fix this problem, if the cable isn't usable?

Comment: If that cable doesn't exist, then it's built into the logic board.  The sensor is still there, it's just not a user serviceable part.